# Install Private Key of a pkcs12 into Mono Cert Store on Linux Programmatically

Tags: c#, linux, mono, private-key, pkcs#12

On .NET in a Windows Environment, if a .pfx/.p12 contains a Private Key, it could be programmatically installed into the Certificate Store in the following way (where rawData is a byte array containing the full .pfx/.p12, both public and private key, and password is the password to the .pfx/.p12):

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(rawData, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

I am looking to do the exact same thing on Mono in a Linux environment. The above code, which works on Windows, will only install the public key of the Certificate on Linux and not the private key. I've been able to manually install the private key of a .p12 using Mono's certmgr utility, but I'm looking for a programmatic solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this answer that won't solve your problem.
Mono doesn't support persisting a private key to a certificate store.
The (highly) technical ang gory details can be found in 
[this interesting discussion](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2010-October/036101.html).

In my app I ended up storing certificates and private keys in database, because anyway my app design required a kind of centralized certificate storage.

Comment: It may be possible to do it 'manually' (outside of Mono) by converting the certificate to a PEM via openssh, then adding it to the mono keystore in /sbin/.config/.mono/keypairs (or wherever mono leaves it) - in which case it's just a matter of the application invoking process.start as appropriate to invoke openssl.